# Error "FindEigen3.cmake" during install kinetic on RPi

Tags: raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all

first: marry  christmas

second : I'm not skilled about install a so large enviroment|software ... so I followed the wiki : install Kinect on raspberry
[http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing ROS Kinetic on the Raspberry Pi](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi)
and at point 3.3 Building the catkin Workspace I have got this error

```
    ==> Processing catkin package: 'geometric_shapes' 
==> Creating build directory: 'build_isolated/geometric_shapes' 
==> Building with env: '/opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh' 
==> cmake /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/geometric_shapes -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/geometric_shapes -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/op
t/ros/kinetic -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G Unix Makefiles in '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/geometric_shapes' 
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2 
bla 
bla
bla
-- Boost version: 1.55.0 
-- Found the following Boost libraries: 
--   system 
--   filesystem 
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:24 (find_package): 
 By not providing "FindEigen3.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has 
 asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3", but 
 CMake did not find one. 

 Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3" with any 
 of the following names: 

   Eigen3Config.cmake 
   eigen3-config.cmake
```

I've read many posts, but it is unclear for me which  cmakelist.txt edit and how to fix it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250727/error-%22findeigen3.cmake%22-during-install-kinetic-on-rpi/) by [AleAle99](https://answers.ros.org/users/28773/aleale99/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-12-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-01-06**:
Did you fix this as I have the same issue

**Comment by [AleAle99](https://answers.ros.org/users/28773/aleale99/) on 2017-01-07**:
burf2000 Sorry, still no solution ....
and unfortunately no idea  about what to do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So my workaround for this was to find anywhere where **find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)** is included in **CMakeList.txt** in the src directory (In each package)

and replace with

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

Second, Find a copy of the **FindEigen3.cmake** file and copy it to the same place as the **CMakeList.txt**.  I found it in another package.

---

Originally posted by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) with karma: 202 on 2017-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AleAle99](https://answers.ros.org/users/28773/aleale99/) on 2017-01-07**:
GREAT!
and to find the string in each CMakeList.txt   can I use a linux command or you did it manually?
are many files to be changed?

thanks!
Ale

**Comment by [AleAle99](https://answers.ros.org/users/28773/aleale99/) on 2017-01-07**:
something like this is right ???

```
grep -r -i "find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)" /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/
```

**Comment by [AleAle99](https://answers.ros.org/users/28773/aleale99/) on 2017-01-07**:
i modified 2 files:

```
~/ros_catkin_ws $ grep -r -i "find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)" ~/ros_catkin_ws/
```

~/ros_catkin_ws/src/robot_state_publisher/CMakeLists.txt:find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
~/ros_catkin_ws/src/geometric_shapes/CMakeLists.txt:find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)

but  same error!!!

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-01-09**:
updated dude :)

**Comment by [AleAle99](https://answers.ros.org/users/28773/aleale99/) on 2017-01-13**:
hI BURF2000

I copied the file FindEigen3.cmake near the two CMakeLists.txt previously modified in the packages
~/ros_catkin_ws/src/robot_state_publisher/
~/ros_catkin_ws/src/geometric_shapes/

but the error is the same.

**Comment by [HappyPaul](https://answers.ros.org/users/29908/happypaul/) on 2017-04-02**:
Followed the instructions verbatim (for desktop install not ROS-comm) and have the same issue.
This answer fixed my issue. Thanks fo that. Here is a slightly quicker grep command.
`~/ros_catkin_ws $ grep -ri "find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)" . --include '*CMakeLists.txt'`